# Power management of sensor IC

Tags: power, sensor, microchip

I am using Microchip [TC77](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/20092a.pdf) temperature sensor with a battery application. I would like to know if it is worth to turn it on and off let's say every second. Or is there some kind of overhead from the powerup process?

Comment: (Page 1 of the datasheet) "[...] and made available at anytime as a 13-bit two’s **compliment** digital word". Shame on you, Microchip!

Comment: One second may no be worth, but if you don't need quick measurements, you can take a sample every 10 seconds or even few minutes and then save a lot of power with standby

Comment: For anyone who doesn't get @Telaclavo's point, a complIment is a kind word to encourage someone, and the complEment is an inversion.  The datasheet contains a basic spelling error, which *ought to be corrected.*   The statement a valid point which is related to the question but is not an answer: A perfect use case for a comment.  Don't bother flagging such comments as "Not Constructive".  I've reported the issue to webcorrections@microchip.com.

Comment: @clabacchio - "save a lot of power". 2mW, or even less than 1mW at lower supply voltage? That's not what I call a lot.

Comment: @stevenvh depends on the application: I have an indoor photovoltaic powered sensor in which I'm trying to bring down the average power from 30 uW to about 15-20 :) And we are measuring once every 5 minutes, to save power.

Answer (score 4):

Don't keep removing and reconnecting the supply to it. Keep it always powered, and write to the Configuration register to put it in shutdown mode (1 uA max) and bring it back to normal operating mode (400 uA max).

Answer (score 3):

From the datasheet (p.9):

> The first valid temperature conversion
>   will be available approximately 300 ms [...] after power-up.

The table under DC characteristics even mentions 400ms as maximum. So if you power it up once every second it will still have a power duty cycle of 40%. Yes, you can improve on that by sampling less frequent; in 1s temperature won't change much. Anyway, maximum supply current is 400\$\mu\$A, so at 5V that's 2mW, which your battery probably can spare. I would leave it on. That 2mW won't influence your result much either; the sensor is 1°C accurate (which is not bad at all), and 2mW on a PCB mounted SOT23-5 won't cause that large temperature rises.

**edit**
Note that the TC77 will measure the temperature of the PCB, not the air's temperature. That's because thermal resistance in conduction is way lower than in convection, which is the way heat is exchanged with the surrounding air.

Comment: +1 For sensors, it's better to leave them on to avoid warm-up delays which affect acquisition time and accuracy. Instead, a lot of power can be saved by lowering the clock rate of the microprocessor.

Answer (score 0):

According to my reading of the [**TC77 datasheet**](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/20092a.pdf):

- Time to first conversion after a power on or power up from standby is 300 mS typical, 400 mS maximum.

  - Standby current is 1 uA worst case or 0.25% of worst case operating current.
  - It is not immediately obvious that entering standby rather than powering off confers any advantages
  - NB: Standby mode can be triggered either by SPI command OR by reducing Vsupply to <= 1.6V (typical) [Section 3.2 page 9]. Whether PI command, Vdd voltage reduction of turning off is superior depends on you application.

Assuming

- worst case supply current,
- standby current ignored
- shutdown immediately after one conversion cycle,
- coms time minimal,

then -

Supply-current reduction fraction = Kcr say = 400/Tcyle
 Tcycle is time in ms of all of (wakeup, read, shut down, sleep cycle).
 So eg for Tcycle = 1s = 1000 mS cycl
 Current reduction = 400/1000 = 40%.
 ie mean current is 40% of what it would have been.
 eg 160 mA instead of 400 mA.
 Extending tcycle to 5 seconds gives 400/5000 = 8% of original or 92% saving.

---

**SPI line Loading and self heating:**

The data sheet notes that self heating can cause errors of up to 0.5% if the SPI lines are loaded to the maximum level allowed. Keeping SPI output loading as low as reasonably possible is recommended. On off or standby cycling will also reduce self heating, but the effects will be liable to be minimal if SPI loading is not high.